# Duplicate entry condition for MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, duplicates

When I want to write duplicate entry to a UNIQUE column in MySQL I get the error `Duplicate entry '' for key 'UNIQUE'` . Is it possible to use this error as a condition for `if()` statement in PHP?
I use code below to insert entry in column.

```php
$s = "INSERT INTO `table`(`entry`)
if ($conn->query($s) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $s . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: `if ($db->errno == 1062)`

Comment: You can also handle these conditions in-query with `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code for a duplicate key is 1062. The error code is available in `$db->errno`.

```
$s = "INSERT INTO `table`(`entry`) VALUES (...)";
if ($conn->query($s) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} elseif ($conn->errno == 1062) {
    echo "Error: duplicate key";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $s . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```